# Using PostGis' ST_AsPNG() Output to Create Image with PHP

Tags: php, postgis, php-gd

I'd like to create an image based on raster output I'm building from a PostgreSQL spatial database.

I have a query:

```
SELECT (
    ST_AsPNG(
        ST_AsRaster(
           geom, 1.5::double precision, 2::double precision, 11, 11, '8BUI', 100, 0, 0, 0, false
        )
    )
) AS "png" FROM "geom" AS "g" LIMIT 1
```

When I dump the returned result, I get:

```
resource(83) of type (stream)
```

I've tried many combinations of using PHP's built-in functions of working with images, but can't seem to get anywhere in actually drawing the polygon. I always get an issue with 'invalid resource type supplied' or similar.

There seems to be no helpful documentation available - could anyone guide me in the right direction?

Technologies in use:

1. Postgis 2
2. Postgres 9

Answer (score 2):

PostGIS documentation have a chapter (5.3.1) with a

"PHP Example Outputting using ST_AsPNG in concert with other raster functions":

http://postgis.net/docs/using_raster_dataman.html#RT_PHP_Output